# Adding classes to components in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I am trying to make a navbar in sveltekit

The issue I am facing with the method I chose to use is that it gives me the error:

> Classes can only be applied to DOM elements, not components

Here's my code for reference

```html
<IconButton sveltekit:prefetch
   class:active={url !== "/"
    ? currentPage.match(url)
    : url === currentPage}
    href={url}>
    
    <TextBlock variant="bodyStrong">
        {name}
    </TextBlock>
</IconButton>
```

`IconButton` is a component from the third party lib called `fluent-svelte`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the source code for fluent-svelte's `IconButton`](https://github.com/Tropix126/fluent-svelte/blob/main/src/lib/IconButton/IconButton.svelte) (lines 12-14 & 40), you can pass a `class` prop that is subsequently applied to the underlying `a` or `button` element. Any additional props other than `class`, `href`, `disabled` or `element` will also be passed through to the underlying `a` or `button` element, [as stated by the documentation for `IconButton`](https://fluent-svelte.vercel.app/docs/components/iconbutton).

However, you cannot use the Svelte `class:name` *directive* on `IconButton` as that type of directive is indeed restricted to DOM elements.

But you could easily reproduce that directive's behavior:

```html
<script>
    const active = url !== "/"
        ? currentPage.match(url)
        : url === currentPage
</script>

<IconButton
    sveltekit:prefetch
    class={active ? 'active' : ''}
    href={url}
>
// ... your svg code here
</IconButton>
```

and the `active` class will get conditionally applied to the underlying `button` or `a` element.

Comment: ``{`${active ? 'active' : ''}`}`` can probably be simplified to just `{active ? 'active' : ''}`

Comment: @H.B. very true, I'll edit the answer, thank you!

Comment: @anmolplayzz - how are you computing value for `currentPage` ?